# ssrs 2008 column width changes on run and pdf

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have designed a report in SSRS 2008 with three tablix that display data from different SP.  When I designed the report and then previewed it, the report looked perfect.  I deployed the report to our report server and viewed it.  The report displays the last table with several columns that are either too large or too small.  When I then export the report to PDF after I run it on the report server then the report appears the way that I designed it.
Does anyone have an idea what could cause the report to display wrong when it is run but correctly when it is exported to a PDF?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common.  I struggle with this same issue.

Edit: double check CanGrow and CanShrink on both the cells and tablix. Maybe your is interpreted differently and therefore is larger in web view?

Firstly, you're just going to have to play with your settings until it looks like in all output formats.  However, here are a few tips to help:

- Don't use rectangles, ever.  Everything should be in a tablix cell.  You have much finer control and it is less likely to blow up in PDF and web viewer.
- Stay away from your margins. I try to keep at least .25"
- Watch your padding.  If you have top and bottom padding of 4, and your text is 10, but your cell only allows 16, then you're going to have a bad time
- Use Ctrl + Mouse Scroll to zoom in and check formatting.  This won't show a lot of errors, but it's something to check.
- Even though your top cell and top line of the tablix should be identical, they aren't always. I can't tell you why.  However, don't put a BorderStyle on both.  Sometimes the border doubles up and looks wider in some of the output formats.
- Always check all output formats prior to handing your project to QA.  If is very common for report formatting to blow up once deployed. I have to double check Portrait vs. Landscape formatting and my borders. I miss that sometimes.
- Sometimes font sizes can be interpreted differently. There can be very slight differences that can change the sizes of your cells.

I hope this helps.